# How do I SendKeys an ALT TAB?

Tags: vba, excel

Application.SendKeys "{PGDN}", True

Works just fine, however Application.SendKeys "{%TAB}", True and Application.SendKeys "%{TAB}", True do nothing.

How do I execute an alt-tab with sendkeys to switch windows?

Here is the code:

```
Application.SendKeys "{PGDN}", True
Application.SendKeys "{PGDN}", True
xreply = MsgBox("Is this page for women? Record:" & i, vbYesNo, "Gender Checker")   
If xreply = vbYes Then
ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i).Value = vbYes
End If
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
Sub ReturnToWindows()
    Application.SendKeys ("%{TAB}")
    DoEvents
End Sub
```

**Must be run while you are in Excel rather than the VBE**.

Comment: What do you mean run in excel, rather than VBE? How do I make that do something? other than the DoEvents it doesn't look different from what I put.

Comment: I mean run the thing while the spreadsheet is visible and the visible basic editing screen is not visible.  It works for me (Win7 Office7)