# Automatic, open and close a internet browser

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to build a macro which opens a chrome browser en opens a specific page, and then closes it and then goes back to the excel sheet.
I'll get a runtime error 13, what am I doing wrong?

So far I build this:

```
Private Sub test()

Dim objShell As Object
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    objShell.Run "chrome.exe www.google.com"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:00:30"))
    objShell.SendKeys ("^{F4}")
    objShell.SendKeys ("%{TAB}")

End Sub
```

Comment: Lose the day element of your `TimeValue` - eg. `TimeValue("00:00:30")`

Comment: TimeValue only accepts values between 0:00:00 (12:00:00 A.M.) to 23:59:59 (11:59:59 P.M.), inclusive.

Comment: Thx, thats working, only now it is still not closing the tab and switching back to Excel

Answer (score 0):

Editing the timevalue and closing the Visual Basic editor worked for me.

[How do I SendKeys an ALT TAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666468/how-do-i-sendkeys-an-alt-tab)